# Oracle PLSQL: Help Required: Parsing String Collection or Concatenated String

Tags: oracle, plsql

Whenever the length of string `l_long_string` is above 4000 characters, the following code is throwing an error:

```
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

Instead of the nested `regexp_substr` query, when I try to use

```
SELECT column_value 
 FROM TABLE(l_string_coll)
```

it throws:

```
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

How can I modify the dynamic query?

Notes:
 - `l_string_coll` is of type `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S`, and comes as input to my procedure (here, i have just shown as an anonymous block)
 - I'll have to manage without creating a User-defined Type in DB schema, so I am using the in-built `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S`.
 - This is not the actual business procedure, but is close to this. (Can't post the original)
 - Dynamic query has to be there since I am using it for building the actual query with session, current application schema name etc.

```
/*
CREATE TABLE some_other_table
(word_id NUMBER(10), word_code VARCHAR2(30), word VARCHAR2(255));
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (1, 'A', 'AB');
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (2, 'B', 'BC');
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (3, 'C', 'CD');
INSERT INTO some_other_table VALUES (4, 'D', 'DE');
COMMIT;
*/

DECLARE
    l_word_count  NUMBER(10)      := 0;
    l_counter     NUMBER(10)      := 0;
    l_long_string VARCHAR2(30000) := NULL;
    l_dyn_query   VARCHAR2(30000) := NULL;
    l_string_coll DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S;

BEGIN
    -- l_string_coll of type DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2S comes as Input to the procedure
    FOR i IN 1 .. 4100
    LOOP
        l_counter := l_counter + 1;
        l_string_coll(l_counter) := 'AB';
    END LOOP;
    -- Above input collection is concatenated into CSV string 
    FOR i IN l_string_coll.FIRST .. l_string_coll.LAST
    LOOP
        l_long_string := l_long_string || l_string_coll(i) || ', ';
    END LOOP;
    l_long_string := TRIM(',' FROM TRIM(l_long_string));
    dbms_output.put_line('Length of l_long_string = ' || LENGTH(l_long_string));
    /*
    Some other tasks in PLSQL done successfully using the concatenated string l_long_string
    */
    l_dyn_query := ' SELECT COUNT(*)
                     FROM   some_other_table
                     WHERE  word IN ( SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL)) word
                                      FROM   ( SELECT :string str FROM SYS.DUAL )
                                      CONNECT BY TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, ''[^,]+'', 1, LEVEL)) IS NOT NULL )';
                     --WHERE  word IN ( SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(l_string_coll) )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_dyn_query INTO l_word_count USING l_long_string;
    dbms_output.put_line('Word Count = ' || l_word_count);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('SQLERRM = ' || SQLERRM);
      dbms_output.put_line('FORMAT_ERROR_BAKCTRACE = ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I modify the dynamic query?

First of all. Based on the code you've provided, there is absolutely no need to use dynamic, native or `DBMS_SQL` dynamic SQL at all.

Secondly, SQL cannot operate on "strings" that are greater than 4K bytes in length(Oracle versions prior to 12c), or 32K bytes(Oracle version 12cR1 and up, if `MAX_STRING_SIZE` initialization parameter is set to `EXTENDED`).

PL/SQL, on the other hand, allows you to work with `varchar2()` character strings that are greater than 4K bytes (up to 32Kb) in length.  If you just need to count words in a comma separated sting, you can simply use `regexp_count()` regular expression function(Oracle 11gr1 and up) as follows:

```
set serveroutput on;
set feedback off;
clear screen;
declare
  l_str        varchar2(100) := 'aaa,bb,ccc,yyy';
  l_numOfWords number;
begin
  l_numOfWords := regexp_count(l_str, '[^,]+');
  dbms_output.put('Number of words: ');
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(l_numOfWords));   
end;
```

Result:

```
Number of words: 4
```